# Почему маркеры, созданные на Яндекс Картах версии 2.1, не являются кликабельными

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Здравствуйте! Почему созданные маркеры на Яндекс.Картах версии 2.1 не являются кликабельными или  реагируют на события в другом месте? В чем может быть причина этой проблемы?

Cайт где посмотреть [тут](https://aza.aswebgroups.ru/)

Мой код:

```js
var catId, flag, ymaps;
adjustcenter=adjustcenter==1?true:false; 
ymaps.ready(initializeMap);

function initializeMap() {
    if (label_position === null || label_position === undefined || label_position.length === 0) {
    label_position = [10,40];
    } else {
    label_position = [Number(label_position[0]), Number(label_position[1])];
}
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map(&quot;app&quot;,
                        { center: loc, 
                            zoom: zoom, 
                            controls: [new ymaps.control.ZoomControl({ options: { size: &quot;small&quot;, position: { right:label_position[0] , bottom:label_position[1] } } })] },
                        { suppressMapOpenBlock: true, 
                            yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity: true }
        )
    myMap.behaviors.disable(&quot;scrollZoom&quot;);

    var objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({ clusterize: true, gridSize: 32 });

    objectManager.clusters.options.set({
        preset: &quot;islands#blueClusterIcons&quot;,
        balloonContentLayout: &quot;cluster#balloonCarousel&quot;,
        clusterBalloonPagerSize: 5,
        clusterBalloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0,
        balloonContentLayoutWidth: 400,
        balloonContentLayoutHeight: 300,
    });

    var activeObjectMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(objectManager.clusters.state);
    objectManager.objects.events.add(&quot;click&quot;, function (e) {
        var objectId = e.get(&quot;objectId&quot;);
        setBalloonData(objectId);
    });

    activeObjectMonitor.add(&quot;activeObject&quot;, function () {
        var objectId = activeObjectMonitor.get(&quot;activeObject&quot;).id;
        setBalloonData(objectId);
    });

    function hasBalloonData(objectId) {
        return objectManager.objects.getById(objectId).properties.balloonContent;
    }

    function setBalloonData(objectId) {
        if (!hasBalloonData(objectId)) {
            getBalloonData(objectId).done(function (data) {
                var object = objectManager.objects.getById(objectId);
                object.properties.balloonContent = data;
                var objectState = objectManager.getObjectState(objectId);
                if (objectState.isClustered) {
                    objectManager.clusters.balloon.open(objectState.cluster.id);
                } else {
                    objectManager.objects.balloon.open(objectId);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    getPlacemarks();

    function getCheckedBoxes(chkboxName) {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);
        var checkboxesChecked = [];
        for (var i = 0; i &lt; checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i].value);
            }
        }
        return checkboxesChecked.length &gt; 0 ? checkboxesChecked : null;
    }

    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    jQuery(&quot;#mapFilter&quot;).click(function () {
        catId = getCheckedBoxes(&quot;cats&quot;);
                console.log(catId)
        if (flag === catId) {
            return false;
        }
        objectManager.removeAll();
        getPlacemarks(catId);
    });

    function getPlacemarks(catId) {
      
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: &#39;/wp-json/v3/maps&#39;,
            dataType: &quot;json&quot;
        })
        .done(function (data) {
                    
                    if (typeof catId === &quot;undefined&quot; || catId === null) {
                        objectManager.add(data[postarraypos].map);
                    } else {
                        var r = {
                            id: data[postarraypos].map.id,
                            type: &quot;FeatureCollection&quot;,
                            features: data[postarraypos].map.features
                    };
                    
                    if (Array.isArray(catId) &amp;&amp; catId.length &gt; 0) {
                            r.features = r.features.filter(function(item) {
                                    return catId.includes(item.category);
                            });
                    }
                    
                    objectManager.add(r);               
                
                }
                var maxLat = 0,
                maxLon = 0,
                minLat = 100,
                minLon = 100;

        objectManager.objects.each(function (object) {
                var lat = object.geometry.coordinates[0];
                var lon = object.geometry.coordinates[1];
                maxLat = lat &lt;= maxLat ? maxLat : lat;
                maxLon = lon &lt;= maxLon ? maxLon : lon;
                minLat = lat &gt;= minLat ? minLat : lat;
                minLon = lon &gt;= minLon ? minLon : lon;
        }, myMap);
                
                if (adjustcenter) {
                        myMap.setBounds([
                                [minLat, minLon],
                                [maxLat, maxLon]
                        ]);
                }
                
                flag = catId;
                jQuery(&quot;#app&quot;).removeClass(&quot;loading&quot;);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            console.log(&quot;error&quot;);
        });
    }

    function getBalloonData(objectId) {
            var dataDeferred = ymaps.vow.defer();
           jQuery.ajax({
                url: &#39;/wp-json/v3/maps&#39;,
                dataType: &quot;json&quot;
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                var result =data[postarraypos].html.filter(function(item) {
                    return item.id===objectId;
            });
            
        var icon = &quot;&quot;;
            var street = &quot;&quot;;
            var size = &quot;&quot;;
            var img = &quot;&quot;;
            var url = &quot;&quot;;
            var urlHtml = &quot;&quot;;
            var linkHtml = &quot;&quot;;
            var desc = &quot;&quot;;
            var html=&quot;Объект пустой&quot;;
            if (Array.isArray(result) &amp;&amp; typeof result[0] === &#39;object&#39; &amp;&amp; result != undefined || result.length != 0) {
                    icon = result[0].icon !== undefined ? result[0].icon:  &quot;&quot;;
                    street = result[0].street !== undefined ? result[0].street:  &quot;&quot;;
                    size = result[0].size !== undefined ? result[0].size:  &quot;&quot;;
                    img = result[0].img !== undefined ?  result[0].img:  &quot;&quot;;
                    url = result[0].url !== undefined ?  result[0].url:  &quot;&quot;;
                    desc = result[0].desc !== undefined ? result[0].desc:  &quot;&quot;;
                    if(url!=null &amp;&amp; url!=&quot;&quot; &amp;&amp; url !== undefined){
                        urlHtml=`&lt;div class=&quot;baloon_more&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;${url}&quot;&gt;Подробнее&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;`;
                        linkHtml=`&lt;a href=&quot;${url}&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;${img}&quot; class=&quot;img-responsive&quot; &gt;&lt;/a&gt;`;
                    }else{
                        
                        linkHtml=`&lt;img src=&quot;${img}&quot; class=&quot;img-responsive&quot; &gt;`;
            }

                            var widthTd = parseFloat(size[0]) + 5;
                            html = `&lt;div class=&quot;baloon_wrap&quot; style=&quot;display:block; overflow: hidden;&quot;&gt;
                                    &lt;table class=&quot;baloon_header_tbl&quot;&gt;
                                    &lt;tbody&gt;
                                    &lt;tr&gt;
                                    &lt;td style=&quot;width:${widthTd}px;&quot;&gt;
                                            &lt;img src=&quot;${icon}&quot; style=&quot;width:${size[0]}px;  height: ${size[1]}px;&quot;&gt;
                                    &lt;/td&gt;
                                     &lt;td&gt;
                                    &lt;div class=&quot;baloon_title&quot;&gt;${street}&lt;/div&gt;
                                    &lt;/td&gt;
                                    &lt;/tr&gt;
                                    &lt;/tbody&gt;
                                    &lt;/table&gt;
                                    &lt;hr&gt;
                                    &lt;div class=&quot;center-block&quot;&gt;
                                    &lt;p&gt;${desc}&lt;/p&gt;                
                                    ${linkHtml}
                                    ${urlHtml}
                                    &lt;/div&gt;
                                    &lt;/div&gt;`;
                    
            } else {
                    console.log(&quot;result не является массивом с объектами&quot;);
            }
                dataDeferred.resolve(html);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            console.log(&quot;full-story error&quot;);
            dataDeferred.resolve(&quot;error&quot;);
        });
                
                return dataDeferred.promise();

    }


        
        var filterInput = document.getElementById(&#39;filterInput&#39;);
        if(filterInput){
        var mapFilter = document.getElementById(&#39;mapFilter&#39;);
        var suggestions = document.getElementById(&#39;suggestions&#39;);
        
        filterInput.addEventListener(&#39;input&#39;, filterItems);
        
        function filterItems() {
                var filterText = filterInput.value.toLowerCase();
                var spansInsideLabels = mapFilter.querySelectorAll(&#39;label span&#39;);
        
                var matchingItems = [];
        
                spansInsideLabels.forEach(function(span) {
                        var label = span.parentNode; // Получаем родительский элемент &lt;label&gt;
                        var labelContent = span.textContent.toLowerCase();
        
                        if (labelContent.includes(filterText)) {
                                label.style.display = &#39;flex&#39;;
        
                                var suggestion = document.createElement(&#39;div&#39;);
                                suggestion.textContent = span.textContent;
                                suggestion.addEventListener(&#39;click&#39;, function() {
                                        filterInput.value = span.textContent;
                                        suggestions.innerHTML = &#39;&#39;;
                                        suggestions.style.display = &#39;none&#39;;
                                });
                                matchingItems.push(suggestion);
                        } else {
                                label.style.display = &#39;none&#39;;
                        }
                });
        
                suggestions.innerHTML = &#39;&#39;;
                
                if (filterText.length &gt; 0 &amp;&amp; matchingItems.length &gt; 0) {
                    matchingItems.forEach(function(item) {
                        suggestions.appendChild(item);
                    });
                    suggestions.style.display = &#39;block&#39;;
                } else {
                    var noMatch = document.createElement(&#39;div&#39;);
                    noMatch.textContent = &#39;Ничего не найдено&#39;;
                    suggestions.appendChild(noMatch);
                    suggestions.style.display = &#39;block&#39;;
                    
                }
                if(!filterText.length){
                        suggestions.innerHTML = &#39;&#39;;

                        suggestions.style.display = &#39;none&#39;;
                    }
        }
        
        document.addEventListener(&#39;click&#39;,closeSuggestions);
    function    closeSuggestions(){
        suggestions.innerHTML = &#39;&#39;;

        suggestions.style.display = &#39;none&#39;;

    }}
}
```

Comment: Вы бы сделали пример кода на отдельной страничке, может кто и глянул бы. В том же jsbin.com А то разместили в WordPress непонятно каким образом, тут и не поймёшь, плагин WordPress виноват ли, или в коде что не так.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по тому, как у вас выводятся иконки, задано неправильное смещение.

```html
<ymaps class="ymaps-2-1-79-image " 
style="position: absolute; 
left: -11px; top: -38px; width: 30px; height: 30px; 
opacity: 1; background-position: 0px 0px; 
background-size: 30px 30px; 
background-image: url(&quot;https://aza.aswebgroups.ru/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/icon.png&quot;);"></ymaps>
```

Ширина и высота иконки - 30px, значит смещение должно быть не `left: -11px; top: -38px;`, а `left: -15px; top: -15px;`.

Смещение задаётся параметром iconImageOffset. У вас в данных, приходящих с бэкэнда задан параметр `"iconImageSize":["30","30"]`. Добавьте ещё `"iconImageOffset":["-15","-15"]`

Comment: А как её задать?

Comment: Тут всё серьёзней кажется, чем простое смещение. Посмотрите активную кликабельную зону по курсору — вся территория выше самой нижней и левее второй справа метки вызывают балун одной из двух точек. Потому и говорю — выносите в песочницу код из вашего WordPress, чтобы нормально дебажить.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Я решил  проблему , всем спасибо. Дело  было в объекте, который принимает размер. У меня  было iconImageSize:[29.35],. Покурил доки яндекса  оказывается icon_ImageSize.   Вот всё работает https://geo.webaxpro.ru/